# Coulnd't get the output for angularJS in the browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-boot

I am trying to use http.get and http.post method in angularJS. My html page and js file are as follows,

```
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="./../js/app.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">
  <p>Username : <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
   <p>Quote : <input type="text" ng-model="quote"></p>

  <button ng-click="ctrl.add();" name="button"  type="button">Add</button>
  <button ng-click="ctrl.retrieve();" name="button" type="button">Retrieve Price</button>
    <p>The results here</p>

<table>
  <tr>
  <th>Quote</th>
  <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="q in quotes"> 
    <td>{{q.quote}}</td>
    <td>{{q.price}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.timeout = 20000;
}])
app.controller('myCtrl', function($http, $scope) {

    this.retrieve = function() {
    $http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8302/api/stock-service/rest/stock/' + $scope.name)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log('inside'+ response);
        $scope.quotes = response.data;
    }, function (response) {
        console.log('came here');
    });
    }

    this.add = function() {
        var message = {
            userName: $scope.name,
            quotes: [$scope.quote]
        }
        $http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8302/api/db-service/rest/db/add', message)
            .then(function(response) {
                $scope.quotes = response.data;
            }, function(response) {
                console.log('error..');
            });
    }
});
```

But I couldn't find the output in the browser. Actually, I can see that request is sending through the particular uri. I am sure it is working in the back end at-least http.get method, but I have no idea why I am not getting the output.
In the command line I can see as follows,

**2020-08-23 16:42:38.871  INFO 20060 --- [nio-8301-exec-6] y.quotes.query1v7.QuotesRequest          : Sending request: https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=GOOG**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you are sure that http.get() is actually firing the api call, what is the response that you are receiving from that api call? Did you check that in the network > response under devTools?

Comment: It seems failed to load response data in the network>response.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could able to solve this problem by adding cross domain CORS extension in google chrome.

[cross domain CORS extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byrPr.png)

May be it can be a temporary solution.